# A word for "mapping existing steps into a larger future plan that commences now"

Tags: word-choice, conditional-future

I'm looking for a word or phrase to mean: “mapping existing and ongoing steps into a larger future plan that commences now”.

I was thinking about "conforming execution" or "collapsing and initiating plan".
Is there a better word or phrase?

Comment: You could be "generalizing" your plans; making them more broadly applicable, less tied to specific details.

Comment: I'd be "**synergizing existing plans with long term policy goals**" myself, if I worked in an environment where such talk was called for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already some great suggestions here, but I might consider *amalgamated*

'We have *amalgamated* our plans'

> amalgamate - Combine or unite to form one organization or structure

I concede it does not necessarily give consideration to a larger view. It gives the impression that the integration is strong and well thought through, however.

Comment: Similarly, I would consider 'dovetail' 
- to fit together in a pleasing or satisfying way.
'We have dovetailed this into our future plan'

Comment: "Amalgamate" works best.  An excellent set of answers here, overall.  Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

How about "[consolidating](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consolidate)"? It essentially means "to merge", but is associated with an improvement over an existing baseline.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. It gives the sense of collating and merging with a larger plan in mind.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are ***incorporating*** them into your future plan.

Comment: "Incorporating" implies mostly an absorption element, does it not? Or does it also imply consideration of a larger view?

Comment: It means making them a part of the larger plan, assimilating them. If you mean to imply that the existing steps are the bulk of the new plan then maybe "reorganizing" or "restructuring" would work.

Answer (score 1):

["Sequence"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sequence). Your wording implies to me that the steps are known, but it is not known when they should be executed. They may be sequenced for the benefit of the one carrying out the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try "merging plans."

The word merge means to join two things together and continue on.

Comment: Does "merging" also include the sense of reassembly required to adhere to a larger plan that is going to begin now?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. Please take a moment to find upvoted answers to see the type of answer this site is looking for. We also provide [help on answering questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Answers should ideally include some sort of independent corroboration, [correctly referenced](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).